# Nested Cursor based update

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, nested, sql-update, cursor

So this is for a SSRS report so I'm using temp tables. I have two tables, one for transactions that I'm just using it to pull the account and the amounts. The second is amortized delinquency information I'm trying to adjust based on the transaction but I'm running into syntax issues. Are case statements not allowed to be used with cursors or updates?

```
--Example Transaction:Account 123456 Principal 500.00 Interest 250.00

delinquent 5 months of 200 principal each month, the transaction had  principal amount of 500, the first two are left alone, the third is reduced to 100 to match the total to the transaction amount, leaving a remaining amount of 0

--Delinquent data
-- 11/2015 Prin 200 Int 80 -> Prin 0   Int 0 (running total  Prin 500 Int 250)
-- 10/2015 Prin 200 Int 80 -> Prin 0   Int 10 (running total  Prin 500 Int 250)
--  9/2015 Prin 200 Int 80 -> Prin 100 Int 80 (running total  Prin 500 Int 240)
--  8/2015 Prin 200 Int 80 -> Prin 200 Int 80 (running total  Prin 400 Int 160)
--  7/2015 Prin 200 Int 80 -> Prin 200 Int 80 (running total  Prin 200 Int 80) <- process starts from the oldest and goes up.
```

This requires the use of a cursor because I cannot process in a set as it has to start with the oldest row, adjust, find the remaining total, then carry on adjusting the next row. If the transaction amount is reached, the remaining rows are zeroed out. I'm then returning the remaining amounts to the transaction table.

```
Declare  TranCursor Cursor FORWARD_ONLY 
For Select LoanNumber, PrincipalCollected, InterestCollected, ServiceFee, PayoffPrincipal,PayoffInterest,PayoffServiceFee
From #transFinal 
FOR UPDATE OF PayoffPrincipal,PayoffInterest,PayoffServiceFee


Open TranCursor;
Fetch next from TranCursor into @TranLoan, @TranPrin, @TranInt, @TranServ, @POPrin,@POInt,@POServ
while (@@Fetch_status = 0) 
Begin
    --Process this individual loan's transaction by going through each set of amortized amounts starting with the oldest and reducing excess of transaction amounts to zero. 
    --eg. delinquent 3 months of 200 principal each month, the transaction had principal amount of 500, the first two are left alone, the third is reduced to 100 to match the total to the transaction amount
    --Transaction Principal 500 Interest 250
    --Delinquent data
    -- 11/2015 Prin 200 Int 80 -> Prin 0   Int 0 (running total  Prin 500 Int 250)
    -- 10/2015 Prin 200 Int 80 -> Prin 0   Int 10 (running total  Prin 500 Int 250)
    --  9/2015 Prin 200 Int 80 -> Prin 100 Int 80 (running total  Prin 500 Int 240)
    --  8/2015 Prin 200 Int 80 -> Prin 200 Int 80 (running total  Prin 400 Int 160)
    --  7/2015 Prin 200 Int 80 -> Prin 200 Int 80 (running total  Prin 200 Int 80) <- process starts from the oldest and goes up.
    Declare  DelqCursor  CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY 
    FOR select LoanNumber,DelqPrin ,DelqInt  ,DelqServFee from #dq 
        where LoanNumber = @TranLoan
        Order by PaidToDate Asc
        For update OF DelqPrin, DelqInt, DelqServFee;
        Open DelqCursor;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Processing individual row of delinquent data
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fetch next from DelqCursor into  @DelqPrin, @DelqInt, @DelqServ, @DelqPTD --, @POPrin,@POInt,@POServ
while (@@Fetch_status = 0) 
    BEGIN


            CASE when @TranPrin = 0 then set @DelqPrin = 0 -- Syntax error on case
                WHEN @TranPrin >0 and @TranPrin > @DelqPrin then -- Syntax error on when
                    set @TranPrin = @TranPrin - @DelqPrin
                    set @ColPrin = @ColPrin + @DelqPrin
                WHEN @TranPrin >0 and @TranPrin < @DelqPrin then 
                    set @ColPrin = @ColPrin + @TranPrin
                    set @TranPrin = 0 
                    set @DelqPrin = @DelqPrin -@TranPrin
            end

            CASE when @TranInt = 0 then set @DelqInt = 0
                WHEN @TranInt >0 and @TranInt > @DelqInt then 
                    set @TranInt = @TranInt - @DelqInt
                    set @ColInt = ColInt + @DelqInt
                WHEN  @TranInt >0 and @TranInt < @DelqInt then 
                    set @ColInt = @ColInt + @TranInt
                    set @TranInt = 0 
                    set @DelqInt = @DelqInt -@TranInt
            end

            CASE when @TranServ = 0 then set @DelqServFee = 0
                WHEN  @TranServ >0 and @TranServ> @DelqServ then 
                    set @TranServ = @TranServ - @DelqServ
                    set @ColServ = ColServ + @DelqServ
                WHEN  @TranServ >0 and @TranServ < @DelqServ then 
                    set @ColServ = @ColServ + @TranServ
                    set @TranServ = 0 
                    set @DelqServ = @DelqServ -@TranServ
            end

Fetch next from DelqCursor into  @DelqPrin, @DelqInt, @DelqServ, @DelqPTD 
End
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--All rows of delinquent data for a single loan have been processed. Now we update the Payoff columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Set @PoPrin =  @ColPrin
Set @PoInt =  @ColInt
Set @PoServ =  @ColServ
--Todo Finish update statement for outside loop to update transaction table
Close DelqCursor-- Finished with delinquent data for this loan. We close the cursor
Fetch next from TranCursor into @TranLoan, @TranPrin, @TranInt, @TranServ, @POPrin,@POInt,@POServ --Start Processing next loan
End 

Close TranCursor
deallocate DelqCursor
deallocate TranCursor
```

I'd appreciate any insight I can get to figure out why my case when statements are giving me errors. I see nothing in the msdn syntax that would prevent case logic from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have coded your `CASE` statements will not work. Case logic needs to happen within a `SELECT`, or `SET`. Yours are just *out there*, and the `SET` is in the middle, after the `THEN`.

You will need to change your logic to something like this for each `CASE` you have in your code.

```
IF @TranPrin = 0 
    SET @DelqPrin = 0 

IF @TranPrin >0 AND @TranPrin > @DelqPrin
BEGIN
    SET @TranPrin = @TranPrin - @DelqPrin
    SET @ColPrin = @ColPrin + @DelqPrin
END

IF @TranPrin > 0 AND @TranPrin < @DelqPrin
BEGIN
    SET @ColPrin = @ColPrin + @TranPrin
    SET @TranPrin = 0 
    SET @DelqPrin = @DelqPrin -@TranPrin
END
```

[CASE (Transact SQL) Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Not sure how I missed the fact it wasn't in a select or set. Thanks.