# Converting nested cursor into a set based approach?

Tags: sql-server, variables, reporting-services, cursor

So I finally finished the update code for my query
[Nested Cursor based update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404242/nested-cursor-based-update)
(I couldn't get the update cursor to work so I just inserted all the variables into a different table and left join + coalesce to correct the numbers. The "for update" statements are still in the cursor declarations because taking them out breaks the cursor even if i remove all the update statements)

but when I tried to copy and paste into SSRS, all the variables being used for the cursors are considered "undeclared"

> The variable name '@TranLoan' has already been declared. Variable names must  be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@TranPrin".
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@DelqPrin".

[this continues for the same variables once per time each variable shows up in the code, and all the variables for both cursors are in the list with the same error]
The thing is @TranLoan is only declared once. Attached is a simplified version of the code (basically only doing it for 1 amount per loan instead of 3)
I'd love it if someone could come up with a set based approach so I can ditch these cursors entirely.

Table setup

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#DQ') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DQ
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#DelqAmts') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DelqAmts
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Tran') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Tran
--IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#DelqAmts') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DelqAmts
CREATE TABLE #DQ
([LoanNumber] int, [Amount] money, [PaidToDate] datetime);
CREATE TABLE #DelqAmts
([LoanNumber] int, [Amount] money, [PaidToDate] datetime);
INSERT INTO #DQ
([LoanNumber], [Amount], [PaidToDate])
VALUES
(56452, 739.97, '2015-09-01 00:00:00'),
(56452, 738.35, '2015-10-01 00:00:00'),
(56452, 736.72, '2015-11-01 00:00:00'),
(56452, 735.08, '2015-12-01 00:00:00'),
(56452, 733.44, '2016-01-01 00:00:00'),
(56452, 731.79, '2016-02-01 00:00:00'),
(56452, 730.13, '2016-03-01 00:00:00'),
(56452, 728.46, '2016-04-01 00:00:00'),
(56452, 726.79, '2016-05-01 00:00:00'),
(56452, 725.1, '2016-06-01 00:00:00'),
(78553, 436.43, '2016-02-01 00:00:00'),
(78553, 435.72, '2016-03-01 00:00:00'),
(78553, 435, '2016-04-01 00:00:00'),
(78553, 434.28, '2016-05-01 00:00:00'),
(78553, 433.55, '2016-06-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE #Tran
([LoanNumber] int, [TranAmount] money);
INSERT INTO #Tran
(LoanNumber, TranAmount)
VALUES
(56452, 833.97),
(78553, 1653.17);
```

End of table setup

```
declare  @Col money = 0 -- Total Collected principal
, @TranLoan varchar(10) --Loan number for current transaction
, @TranPrin money = 0 -- Tran loan collected principal
, @POPrin money = 0 -- Tran loan collected principal
, @TranCursor as CURSOR
, @DelqLoan varchar(10)
, @DelqPrin money  -- Current loan collected principal
, @DelqPTD date 
, @DelqCursor as CURSOR


set  @TranCursor = Cursor FORWARD_ONLY 
For Select LoanNumber, [TranAmount]
From #Tran

Open @TranCursor;
Fetch next from @TranCursor into @TranLoan, @TranPrin

set @Col = 0 

while (@@Fetch_status = 0) 
Begin

select @TranLoan as Loan, @TranPrin as TPrin
set  @DelqCursor = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY 
FOR select LoanNumber,Amount ,PaidToDate 
from #DQ
    where LoanNumber = @TranLoan 
    Order by PaidToDate Asc;
--  For update OF Amount;
    Open @DelqCursor

        Fetch next from @DelqCursor into  @DelqLoan,  @DelqPrin,@DelqPTD

        while (@@Fetch_status = 0) 
    
        Begin
            IF @TranPrin = 0 
            SET @DelqPrin = 0 
        End

        IF @TranPrin > 0 AND @TranPrin < @DelqPrin
        BEGIN
            SET @Col = @Col + @TranPrin 
            SET @DelqPrin = @TranPrin 
        --      select @TranLoan as Loan, @TranPrin as TPrin, @DelqPrin as DPrin, @DelqPTD as PTD, @Col as Col
                SET @TranPrin = 0
        END

        IF @TranPrin >0 AND @TranPrin > @DelqPrin
        BEGIN
            SET @TranPrin = @TranPrin - @DelqPrin
            SET @Col = @Col + @DelqPrin
        END
        
        Insert into #DelqAmts values (@DelqLoan,  @DelqPrin, @DelqPTD)
    Fetch next from @DelqCursor into @DelqLoan,   @DelqPrin,@DelqPTD
    End

    Close @DelqCursor-- Finished with delinquent data for this loan. We close the cursor
Fetch next from @TranCursor into @TranLoan, @TranPrin
End 

Close @TranCursor
deallocate @DelqCursor
deallocate @TranCursor

select * from #delqAmts -- This is a simplification of what I need out of this code block and isn't the end result of the report
```

The variables are not used after this point so the rest of the code is not included.

Comment: You really need to trash this nested cursor approach and make this a set based approach instead. There is nothing in here that suggests you need to do anything more than a couple of update statements to replace this whole thing.

Comment: I need to loop through each loan's delinquent lines individually based on the date in ascending order to calculate the running total up to that date and subtract whatever is in excess of the transaction amount.

Comment: Read the example where it says : Delinquent 3 months of 200 principal each month, the transaction had principal amount of 500, the first two are left alone, the third is reduced to 100 to match the total to the transaction amount

Comment: By all means show me a set based approach where you tackle one to many lines and handle a rolling total  based on date

Comment: So I think your question is how to make this work in SSRS? I would suggest moving this to a stored proc and then at the end have a select statement to return the values you want. As far as converting this into set based I am certain it can be done but we don't have tables or data to work with. And honestly that much effort is way beyond the scope of an online forum.

Comment: a SP would be nice but not feasible for how often a report like this gets updated (lengthy change control process for all database objects). I'd be interested in seeing your take on a set based approach. I've trimmed down the code to illustrate the problem better (and removed 2/3rds of the variables since they were just doing the same thing but with different sets of numbers) as well as added a sample dataset and table setups.

Comment: Yes that makes the problem a lot more manageable. What version of sql server are you using? Running totals have gotten a lot easier with 2012+.

Comment: Yeah running 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking over the documentation on over and how to do rolling sums this became alot easier. Here is the final query (minus table setups)

```
    select LoanNumber, PaidToDate, PrincipalCollected,

    SumPrin, DelqPrin, 
    case when SumPrin <= PrincipalCollected then DelqPrin 
    When PrincipalCollected between SumPrin-DelqPrin and SumPrin then PrincipalCollected- (SumPrin-DelqPrin)
        when SumPrin > PrincipalCollected  then 0 
        end  as ColPrin,
    InterestCollected, SumInt, DelqInt, 
    case when SumInt <= InterestCollected then DelqInt 
        When InterestCollected between SumInt-DelqInt and SumInt then InterestCollected- (SumInt-DelqInt)
        when SumInt > InterestCollected  then 0 
        end  as ColInt,
    ServiceFee, SumServ, DelqServFee, 
        case when SumServ <= ServiceFee then DelqServFee 
        When ServiceFee between SumServ-DelqServFee and SumServ then ServiceFee- (SumServ-DelqServFee)
        when SumServ > ServiceFee  then 0 
        end  as ColServ
        from (
SELECT tf.LoanNumber,tf.PrincipalCollected,InterestCollected, ServiceFee, 
dq.PaidToDate,  
DelqPrin, SUM(DelqPrin) OVER (Partition by dq.LoanNumber ORDER BY dq.PaidToDate) as SumPrin,  
DelqInt, SUM(DelqInt) OVER (Partition by dq.LoanNumber ORDER BY dq.PaidToDate) as SumInt, 
DelqServFee, SUM(DelqServFee) OVER (Partition by dq.LoanNumber ORDER BY dq.PaidToDate) as SumServ

FROM   #tran tf
left join #dq dq on tf.LoanNumber = dq.LoanNumber 
) as A
ORDER BY LOanNumber, PaidToDate
```

Much easier as a set based approach. Just needed to do the rolling sums as a subquery then apply the formula after to get the numbers I need.